# How Can I Transpose/Format Data Like This in Excel

Tags: excel, transpose

Good day everyone. I am working to test a 10-year daily historical bond prices. Kindly see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnKWk.png) to better understand the format I needed. Please take note that due to a large number of records I am dealing with, I find it really tedious to manually format/transpose the data to the required output.

Hope you can guide me on what approach I need to take. Thank you.

P.S. Just to be transparent to everyone, I also posted this question [here.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/965275-how-transpose-data-like.html)

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA? You'll have to write some in order to transpose your data, if you want to keep it all in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Honestly, I am not that familiar in VBA. Hope someone can at least guide me.

Comment: Actually, there is also a "Paste Special" function you can use that will allow you to transpose your data... Google search: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/transpose-excel-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that function but I am having difficulty in the 'Settlement Date' part, which a simple Transpose Data cannot do.

Comment: I see - It's not quite a transpose. Is the sample picture one data point? That is, is that one record? And you need to translate all records into the flattened format Or is it three records?

Comment: Yes, it is only one record which I extracted from my source database.thanks.

Comment: Okay, oh wow - so, can their be more columns to the left? Can there be more rows with more dates? (I'm trying to scope the problem so I, or someone one here, can help)

Comment: And last question: How will more than one record look like in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with data like:

[image]

Running this code:

```
Sub ReMapper()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long, K As Long
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    K = 1
    For rw = 6 To 9 '         loop over rows
        For cl = 2 To 5 '     loop over columns
            s2.Cells(K, "A").Value = Cells(rw, "A").Value
            s2.Cells(K, "B").Value = Cells(5, cl).Value
            s2.Cells(K, "C").Value = Cells(rw, cl).Value
            s2.Cells(K, "D").Value = Cells(4, cl).Value
            K = K + 1
        Next cl
    Next rw
End Sub
```

will put this on *Sheet2*:

[image]

***NOTE:***

1. the code gathers data from the cells I have colored
2. the loops go over the cells that I have formatted **bold**
3. the numerical constants in the code like *{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}* depend on the size and position of the source data.

Comment: Wow, you're such a great help Gary's Student. Whoever Gary was, he must be proud of you. Thanks so much!